# route53 apex/root/naked domain forward to another domain

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-route53

What is the simplest way to set up a 307 from one apex domain to another on AWS Route53?

- thecontent.com - the content
- www.thecontent.com - should 307 to thecontent.com
- otherdomain.net - should 307 to thecontent.com

Here's what I've tried:

1. Create hosted zone for thecontent.com
2. Create AWS bucket with the content and cloudfront distribution.
3. Setup an apex record: A ALIAS d1waasdf05wj5.cloudfront.net.

   - So far, visiting all these URLs works
4. Create a public bucket www.content.com with "Static website hosting".

   - For 301, "Redirect Requests"
   - For 307, "Use this bucket to host a website"
   - Set "Redirection rules"

Redirection rules

```
<RoutingRules>
  <RoutingRule>
    <Redirect>
      <Protocol>https</Protocol>
      <HostName>thecontent.com</HostName>
      <HttpRedirectCode>307</HttpRedirectCode>
    </Redirect>
  </RoutingRule>
</RoutingRules>
```

So far, this works.  `wget --max-redirect 0 http://bucket-endpoint-url` shows a 307

5. Setup www.thecontent.com -> thecontent.com

   - I can setup a CNAME easy to forward www->apex, but that won't work for apex->apex.  An apex can't have a CNAME.
   - So, I read to setup an A record with an ALIAS to the bucket, but the bucket doesn't show up in the alias dropdown...

I get "Alias Target contains an invalid value." from these values:

Name: www, Type: A, Alias: Yes, Alias Target:

- http://www.donotlitterpeople.org.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com
- www.thecontent.com.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com
- www.thecontent.com.
- www.thecontent.com

This A record for the www subdomain would be the same as I'd use on the other domain, right?  What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

Lol, I got a Tumbleweed badge for this question.

My solution was to not use Route53 for all these redirects - AWS is almost guaranteed to be 200+% the cost of other cloud solutions.

Instead, I used https://www.cloudns.net/ for DNS on these smaller less important redirect domains.